# If subquery returns null value for a field update the field with default value

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

How to write a query for the below given condition

update table Set field=(if (subquery returns a not null value) else return default value) where some condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
UPDATE TABLE x SET field = IFNULL(SUBQUERY, default_value) WHERE ...
```